Image of connected components under faithfully flat maps
Assume $\mathrm{Spec}(A)\to \mathrm{Spec}(B)$ is a faithfully flat map of affine schemes, and further assume $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ is connected (as a topological space, or equivalently $B$ only has idempotents $0,1$). Is it true that the image of any two connected components of $\mathrm{Spec} A$ (as topological spaces) intersect in $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$?

No. Take $B = \mathbb C[x,y] / (xy(x-1))$, so that $\operatorname{Spec} B$ consists of three lines in $\mathbb A^2$. Take $\operatorname{Spec} A$ to be the disjoint union over an affine open cover, which contains the open sets $U_0 = \{x=0\} \setminus \{y=0\}$ and $U_1 = \{x = 1\} \setminus \{y=0\}$. Then $U_0$ and $U_1$ are connected components of $\operatorname{Spec} A$, but their images are disjoint.
